# c++ inner class with methods not working

Tags: c++, class

I have a homework assignment due, but I don't understand what is wrong with my code. The name variable is messed up. I look through my textbook and I can't see anything wrong with my code. Please help.

The name has to be stored in an array length of 80 and that was the only way I knew how to do that.

I come from a lot of java experience, so I don't know if there is a syntax thing I am missing or what.

Thanks for your time.

```
//import statements
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//class declaration section
class Student
{
    //declare private instance variables
    private:
        int ssn;
        char* name[80];
        const int ARRAYLENGTH =80;

    //deckale public methods and constructor
    public:
        Student();
        void setName(string);
        int getSSN();
        string getName();
        void setSSN(int);


};

//class implementation section
Student::Student()
{
    //set ssn equal to 99999999 by default
    ssn = 999999999;
    //set name equal to unassigned by default
    string someString ="unassigned";
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH; i++)
    {
        if (i < someString.length())
            name[i] = &someString[i];
        else
            name[i]= "";
    }
}

void Student::setName(string newName)
{
    //assigns the newName to the char array
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH; i++)
    {
        if (i < newName.length())
            name[i] = &newName[i];
        else
            name[i]= "";
    }

    return;
}

int Student::getSSN()
{
    return ssn;
}

string Student::getName()
{
    //make a string from the char array to return a string
    string name1 = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    {
        name1 += *(name+i);
    }
    return name1;
}

void Student::setSSN(int num)
{
    //check to make sure ssn isnt below or equal to 0
    if (num > 0)
        ssn = num;

    return;
}


//main function
int main() {

    Student student1, student2;

    //changing name and ssn of student2
    student2.setName("John Doe");
    student2.setSSN(123456789);

    //printing out information
    cout<< "Name for student1 is "<< student1.getName() <<" and snn is "<< student1.getSSN() <<endl; //name should be unassigned and ssn should be 999999999
    cout<< "Name for student1 is "<< student2.getName() <<" and snn is "<< student2.getSSN() <<endl; //name should be John Doe and ssn should be 123456789

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You need to initialise your char* name[80] using new. Also, what's the reason not using the generic ARRAY_LENGTH in your `char* name[80]`? You need to understand if you want `char* name[80]` or char name[80] - depends on your workscope.

Answer (score 4):

This `char* name[80]` declares an array of pointers.  Perhaps you just want an array of char by using `char name[80]`.  (Which is literally a pointer to the first char of an array)

`char* name[80]` is an array of pointers. (Probably not what you intended)

Answer (score 2):

Some of the mistakes I could point out in single scan are:-

This is wrong :-

```
name[i] = &someString[i];
```

You are trying to take an address of a particular character in string and then throwing it at char*.

Then you are trying to store value in int which is outside its range:-

```
ssn = 999999999;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're changing the SSN of Student2 but you're printing the SSN of student1

Answer (score 0):

This code should solve the problem.

```
//import statements
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//class declaration section
class Student
{
    //declare private instance variables
    private:
        int ssn;
        char name[80];
        const int ARRAYLENGTH =80;

    //deckale public methods and constructor
    public:
        Student();
        void setName(string);
        int getSSN();
        string getName();
        void setSSN(int);


};

//class implementation section
Student::Student()
{
    //set ssn equal to 99999999 by default
    ssn = 999999999;
    //set name equal to unassigned by default
    string someString ="unassigned";
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH; i++)
    {
        if (i < someString.length())
            name[i] = someString[i];
        else
            name[i]= '\0';
    } 
}

void Student::setName(string newName)
{
    //assigns the newName to the char array
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH; i++)
    {
        if (i < newName.length())
            name[i] = newName[i];
        else
            name[i]= '\0';
    }

    return;
}

int Student::getSSN()
{
    return ssn;
}

string Student::getName()
{
    //make a string from the char array to return a string
    string name1 = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    {
        name1 += *(name+i);
    }
    return name1;
}

void Student::setSSN(int num)
{
    //check to make sure ssn isnt below or equal to 0
    if (num > 0)
        ssn = num;

    return;
}


//main function
int main() {

    Student student1, student2;

    //changing name and ssn of student2
    student2.setName("John Doe");
    student2.setSSN(123456789);

    //printing out information
    cout<< "Name for student1 is "<< student1.getName() <<" and snn is "<< student1.getSSN() <<endl; //name should be unassigned and ssn should be 999999999
    cout<< "Name for student1 is "<< student2.getName() <<" and snn is "<< student2.getSSN() <<endl; //name should be John Doe and ssn should be 123456789

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You should use `ARRAYLENGTH` as the capacity of the array to avoid possible differences between the value for `ARRAYLENGTH` and the array capacity, e.g. `char name[ARRAYLENGTH];`.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you mean to store 80 names, it look like a student have only one name.

`char *name[80]` means 80 names, not 80 characters!

Anyway: You cant keep pointer to a local variable, you doing it in many places.

So you better use `const char*` and not by value `string`.
for example:

change `string someString ="unassigned";` to `const char* someString = "unassigned"`

function `Student::setName(string newName)` should be  `Student::setName(const char* newName)`

The other option is to copy, not just assign the pointer. means use `string name[80];` instead of `char* name[80];`
in that case: function `Student::setName(string newName)` better be`Student::setName(const string& newName)`